# String formating in mysql , replace duplicates in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, replace, regexp-replace

I have a column that contains words as this

```
["standard_package"]

["10GB"]

["Application_Data_Add-on"]

["Local Data"]
```

and I wanted to remove the opening [" and closing "], and it worked with this

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(table.col, '"]', ''), '["', '')
```

output:

```
standard_package

10GB

Application_Data_Add-on

Local Data
```

which is what I needed.

but all of a sudden I start seeing values duplicated like

```
["standard_package", "standard_package"]

["Premium_Package", "Premium_Package"]
```

how can I make them be like:

```
standard_package

Premium_Package
```

without effecting the replacing of these values

```
["standard_package"]
["10GB"]
["Application_Data_Add-on"]
["Local Data"]
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe use some grouping. I don't know if the following is supported, but try: `^\["([\w- ]+).*]$` and replace by `\1`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/ls3Ikn/3)

Comment: *but all of a sudden I start seeing values duplicated like* Does multi-value without duplication (like `["standard_package", "Premium_Package"]`) is present? If not then use simple `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, '"', 2), '"', -1)`.